# Unable to install Nvidia drivers 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, dependencies

after running `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` drivers are not installed, because of:

```
 linux-modules-nvidia-455-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-455 (<= 455.38-1) but 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-455 (<= 455.38-1) but 455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve this dependency problem

Comment: Are any PPA connected for nvidia drivers?

Comment: No, i didn't connect any repositories

Comment: It is very unlikely. Check in Software & Updates -> Other Software.

Answer (score 0):

You have connected `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` that has `nvidia-kernel-common-455` version `455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`.

But the Ubuntu repositories have `455.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1` version of this package.

So remove the PPA, run `sudo apt update` andd all should install.

Otherwise you need to do some research about what is wrong with the PPA and you won't use autoinstall.